# Twilio programmable video EVENT CALLBACK URL

Tags: twilio

I am working with Programmable video. I need help to intercept events like Task Created, Task Completed to log it to database for troubleshooting. I am not able to get links/ documentation which explains related Video. Any help please?

Comment: We have achieved this by using assignment call back configuring for workspace in Twilio.

Comment: How did you set up callbacks for server side application? can you please share some sample code or relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details about Room Status Callbacks here: [Rooms Status Callbacks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/status-callbacks)

Here's a sample of the data Twilio sends when a room is created and ends:

```
// created
{
  "AccountSid": "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "RoomName": "MyRoom",
  "RoomSid": "RMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "RoomStatus": "in-progress",
  "SequenceNumber": 0,
  "StatusCallbackEvent": "room-created",
  "Timestamp": "2017-09-12T17:29:51.432Z"
}

// ended
{
  "AccountSid": "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "RoomDuration": "952",
  "RoomName": "MyRoom",
  "RoomSid": "RMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "RoomStatus": "completed",
  "SequenceNumber": 15,
  "StatusCallbackEvent": "room-ended",
  "Timestamp": "2017-09-12T17:45:44.379Z"
}
```

The events for each room have a `SequenceNumber` which auto-increments from 0.